# ffmpeg how to overlay with concat?

Tags: ffmpeg, concatenation, overlay

```
ffmpeg \
-i main.avi\
-i mini.avi\
-filter_complex "[0:v:0][0:a:0][1:v:0][1:a:0]concat=n=2:v=1:a=1[outv][outa]; \
[0:v:1][0:a:0][1:v:1][1:a:0]concat=n=2:v=1:a=1[outvr][outar]" \
-map "[outv]" -map "[outa]" outputMain.mp4 \
-map "[outvr]" -map "[outar]" outputMini.mp4
```

Can I get just One output? The 2 videos are overlayed.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pzgNK.jpg)

Comment: Paste the full output of `ffmpeg -i main.avi -i mini.avi`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use the overlay filter:

```
./ffmpeg -i main.avi -i mini.avi -filter_complex "[0:v][1:v]overlay=50:50[vout]" -map "[vout]" -map 0:a out.mp4
```

The values 50:50 are the offset from the top left (50px left; 50px right).

The overlay doesn't change the video resolution. So it's only working well, if the mini video has already a lower resolution than the main video.

If you wan to scale the mini video also down, use the following command:

```
./ffmpeg -i main.avi -i mini.avi -filter_complex "[1:v]scale=w=720:h=576[vmini];[0:v][vmini]overlay=50:50[vout]" -map "[vout]" -map 0:a out.mp4
```

The filter `scale` is used here to bring the mini video into the correct resolution you want for the overlay.

Comment: thank you for the answer. How can I combine the concat + overlay command?

Comment: For what do you need the concat?